Do we care about the size when saying "I cubed the meat" and "I diced the meat"?
In the dictionary,
cube something: to cut food into cubes
dice something: to cut (food) into small cubes
I guess when you "cube something", the cubed cubes can be big or small
but when you "dice something", the cubed cubes are normally small
But I might be wrong.
Oxford dictionary also says "to cube" and "to dice" are the same or synonyms.
Do we care about the size when saying "I cubed the meat" and "I diced the meat"?

In cookery, cubes are bigger. Typically, cube: 8mm to 12mm (1/3 to 1/2 inch), dice, about 6mm (1/4 inch), mince: 3mm (1/8 inch) or smaller.

Also depends on the food. The pieces of a diced onion could easily have a side length of only 5-10mm (and incidentally aren't actually cubes, but rectangular prisms!), whereas the pieces of a diced potato are more likely to have a side length of 10-20mm. One might argue that this means you're cubing the potato, not dicing it, but the collocation "diced potato" is very common and certainly refers to this size.

In classical cookery, "cubed" is a generic term that does't specify size. You specify size (from largest to smallest) as "large dice", "medium dice", "small dice", or "bruniose". Here is a guide with exact sizes specified.

Trying to state this broadly leaving room for exceptions...
In recipes, cubing tend towards larger pieces and dicing tends towards smaller pieces. A recipe for a beef stew wouldn't say to "dice the meat" but to cut the meat into cubes, and they'd be an inch or more. But you might find a recipe that has you cutting something "into small cubes", cheese perhaps, or day-old bread, and that would be like a pair of dice in a board game.  Onions and peppers often get diced, and that's the size of a fingernail or smaller. But it's an imprecise instruction, so you might might see "finely diced" if the author wants you to go smaller.

But it's an imprecise instruction, so you might might see "finely diced" if the author wants you to go smaller. In recipe books, I've noticed, a picture is worth a thousand words; they aren't there just for food-porn reasons.
